# How to make jedit file-dropdown to display absolute path (not filename followed by directory)?

Tags: jedit

All is in the title.

If a have opened the three files:

- /some/relatively/long/path/dir1/file_a
- /some/relatively/long/path/dir1/file_b
- /some/relatively/long/path/dir2/file_a

The file dropdown contains:

```
file_a (/some/relatively/long/path/dir1)
file_a (/some/relatively/long/path/dir2)
file_b (/some/relatively/long/path/dir1)
```

And that bother me because I have to look on the right to differentiate the two `file_a`, and on the left for the others. This happens a lot to me mostly because I code in python, and thus I often have several `__init__.py` files opened.

How do I get jedit to display

```
/some/relatively/long/path/dir1/file_a
/some/relatively/long/path/dir1/file_b
/some/relatively/long/path/dir2/file_a
```

config:

- jedit 5.1.0
- java 1.6.0_26
- mac osx 10.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not easily possible currently, I just had a look at the source and this is not configurable.

You can:

- Submit a Feature Request to make this configurable (good idea in any case)
- Create or let create a startup macro that

  - registers an `EBComponent` with the `EditBus` that listens for new `EditPane`s getting created
  - retrieve the `BufferSwitcher` from the `EditPane`
  - retrieve the `ListCellRenderer` from the `BufferSwitcher`
  - set a new `ListCellRenderer` to the `BufferSwitcher` that first calls the retrieved `ListCellRenderer` and then additionally sets the text to `value.getPath()`
- Try the `Buffer List` plugin as to whether it maybe suits your needs

Now follows code that implements the work-part of option two, runnable as BeanShell code which does this manipulation for the current edit pane. The third line is not necessary when done in an EBComponent, this is just that the on-the-fly manipulation is shown immediately.

```
r = editPane.getBufferSwitcher().getRenderer();

editPane.getBufferSwitcher().setRenderer(
    new ListCellRenderer() { 
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus) { 
            rc = r.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus); 
            rc.setText(value.getPath()); 
            return rc; 
        } 
    });

editPane.repaint();
```

Comment: I tried your code, it works. But when called at startup, it fails with

 `undefined variable [...] editPane : at line: 1 [...]`. 
I seams `editPane` is not accessible at startup. Would you have an idea how to get access to it?

Comment: Then, there is one limitation to you code: it keep the file sorted by filename. When displaying abspath, it should be sorted by abspath. An idea how to do that?

Comment: You should read answers fully. I clearly stated that this code is only for on-the fly usage, not for the startup code. I described the whole process of how to make it work for all BufferSwitchers in all EditPanes from a startup macro. That code was only part of the deal as clearly stated in the paragraph before the code. ;-) At startup you can have no EditPane, as you are not in the context of an EditPane. And during runtime you can create and discard dozens of EditPanes by splitting, joining, openingn new windows, ... and all have an own BufferSwitcher that needs to be manipulated.

Comment: About sorting, that is easy, just flip the switch in the settings: `Utilities -> Global Options... -> jEdit -> View -> Sort buffer sets by file name, instead of path name`

Comment: Well, I just don't understand the technical parts (no idea what are `EBComponent`, `EditBus`, etc...). I just copied/pasted your code in a macro file, blindly. But in the end, a runtime-macro will be enough :-)